# How can i get a list of files(only sound related .flac, .m4b, .mp3) and folders with them from a directory on the sd card?

Tags: android, file

```
public static File[] filenames;
public static ArrayList<String> shortFilenames;
public static String MyDirectory = "/AudioSamples";


public static ArrayList<String> getFileNames() {
    File sdCardRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + MyDirectory);

        filenames = sdCardRoot.listFiles();
        shortFilenames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File tmpf : filenames) {

                String name = tmpf.getName();
                shortFilenames.add(name);

        }
    return shortFilenames;
}
```

I need to get names of only music files(like m4b,mp3) and folders with music/sounds in it from a directory on the sd card, how can i do it ? My code takes everything, so i need some kind of filter :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static Uri[] mUris;
static String[] mFiles = null;
public static String[] getMusic(){

    File music = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // File asd = Environment.

    // String[] savedFiles = getApplicationContext().fileList();

    File[] musicList = music.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ((name.endsWith(".mp3")||(name.endsWith(".m4b")||(name.endsWith(".flac"))));
        }
    });

    mFiles = new String[musicList.length];
    for(int i=0; i<musicList.length;i++) {
        mFiles[i]=musicList[i].getAbsolutePath();
    }

    return mFiles;
```

Comment: Sorry, i edited question title adding more extensions, and what for we have static Uri[] mUris; and as i understood, this code will help with mp3, how can i add other extensions ?

Comment: this code gives back only files with needed extensions, but what about folders ?

Comment: first be clear with ur question and then ask question in SO..dont unnecessarily change the question again and again...and some time plz google also @Dmitrijs